# How to retrieve @Reference fields / which is best @Reference or @Embedded and SubQuery in MorphiaQuery

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia, nosql

I have a mongodb with two model classes say **User** and **UserInfo**. The criteria is in **User** class  I have to retrieve a multiple fields around 10 fields like `"firstName","lastName"`, etc and in **UserInfo** Model class I like to retrieve only one field say "**age**".

At this moment I referenced the UserInfo class's object to the User class like stated below in the **Structure** and its stores in the DB as  `{"firstName","John"},{"lastName","Nash"},{userInfo: userInfoID}` but if I make an **Embedded** Relation then it would store all the userInfo's fields and I think to retrieve one ("age") field it is Unwanted to Embed all the userInfo's fields which inturn will make the application slow I think.

Which scenario should I use whether @Reference or @Embedded, I think Embedded will slow down my response to DB but in the websites its given as reference annotation only slows down querying time and needs some sort of **Lazy Loading** an all, my structure is like below:

```
class User extends Model{
 public String firstName;
 public String lastName;
 public String loginTime;
 public String logoutTime;
 public String emailId; etc,etc......
  Some more 10 fields like this+userInfo reference object 
  @Reference
  public UserInfo userInfo;
  }   
  class UserInfo extends Model{
 public String emailId;
 public String age;
 public String sex;
 public String address;
 public String bank; etc,etc......
 Some more 10 fields like this
  }
```

As I stated above I want only **age** field from **UserInfo** and **all** fields of **User**, so which Annotation is best and @Reference or @Embedded. It will be  more helpful if I get a single query for User class in which I can retrieve all fields of User and only "age" field of UserInfo. In short I need a query like this when I go for @Reference relationship

```
field("userInfo.age") for userInfo.emailId = (MorphiaQuery q =        User.createMorphiaQuery;           
 q.field("firstName").equal("John");     q.field("lastName").equal("Nash");                                             q.field("loginTime").greaterthan("sometime"))//the complex part where I need age of particular userInfo but I have only the ID of the userInfo since I am using Reference and that Id too got from a **subQuery**....
```

Please don't write two queries I need a single query or maybe a query with subquery. To be more clear I can tell in SQL language:

```
   SELECT age FROM UserInfo where emailId = u.emailId
   (SELECT * FROM User WHERE firstName='John' AND lastName='Nash' AND
       logintime='someTime') AS u;
```

I  need this exact same query without writing two morphia queries which consumes more time by referring two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo does not support query across tables / collections. And such page would satisfy you:

[MongoDB and "joins"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins)

As in sql, the join query is also build intermediate result set and make query again:

[Understanding how JOIN works when 3 or more tables are involved. [SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql)

When you build your model, you should not consider a lot about what single query but structural modeling:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

For your case, if you are using embeded, you can make this in one query and specify the fields you need by using queries like:

```
db.User.find({"some_field":"some_query"},{"firstName":1,....,"userInfo.age":1})
```

Check projections here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

If you are using reference or even soft link like using **Morphia** `Key<>` to lazy load the UserInfo, it requires two queries.

If it's not real-time application, you can also try mongo map-reduce to merge collection to handle big data, though the map-reduce is too bad for mongo though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure you can't with just one query.