# Conceptual SQL JOIN questions involving more than 2 table joins

Tags: sql, join

I'm aware of join with 2 tables. However, I think of the following questions when it comes to joining with 3 or more tables. These may seem very basic but would be great if somebody explained it.
Note I've already gone through the link [Understanding how JOIN works when 3 or more tables are involved. [SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql)

**Query for questions 1 & 2:**

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Regions ON Orders.RegionID = Regions.RegionID;
```

**Question1:**  
`LEFT JOIN Regions ON Orders.RegionID = Regions.RegionID` Does this join occur on the result set of 1st join?

**Question2:** What if the condition was:  
`LEFT JOIN Regions ON Customers.RegionID = Regions.RegionID` Now what happens? On what result set does this join occur? Does it occur on 'FROM Customers' result set or the 1st join result set?

**Query for question 3:**

```
SELECT count(distinct Customers.CustomerName), count(Orders.OrderID), count(Regions.RegionID)
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Regions ON Orders.RegionID = Regions.RegionID;
```

**Question3:**  
Will the result vary if the order of joins were to be reversed? In which case will it vary?

**Query for question 4:**

```
SELECT count(Regions.RegionID)
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Regions ON Orders.RegionID = Regions.RegionID;
```

**Question4:** (This is where I get most confused)  
When it comes to aggregations, what should be the table_name in FROM? Does it depend on the table.column which is to be aggregated?
For the puspose of question, suppose that the 2 joins ARE required and we only want count(RegionID).

Comment: I think like this: The joins will first create a resultset with all combinations (i.e. Customers x Orders x Regions) with the columns from all tables. `ON` + `WHERE` then filters the result.

Comment: By definition a join *always* involves more than one table. There is no "join with a single table" (even if you use the same table twice it's still a join with two tables)

Comment: @adrianm Imagine that with tables containing millions of rows. Bad thing, right? Indexes is the magic word. Filtering is done there before a resultset is built which then gets filtered by `WHERE`.

Comment: @fancyPants, how and in what order filtering happen is an implementation detail

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have three table, with these relationships: Orders linked to customer and to region and also customer are linked to region.

1) Yes it does
2) This second query links customers to region, so here you have the region of your customer before you have the region of your order (that probably may be different). If you want you can obtain both with two join on the region table one for the customer and one for the order
3) With a left join changing the order the result may differ. e.g. in your query you obtain all the customer (eventually also the ones with no orders) and optionally orders and region. If you have something like "...FROM region LEFT JOIN customer ..."  you'll have all the regions and eventually orders made on them.
4) The count affect the result of your joins, and can involve any column in that, not only the one used for the aggregation