# retrieve contacts SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a social network-type web application.
I have a `users` table:

```
___________________________________________________
|user_id|firstname|lastname|password|email|country|
---------------------------------------------------
```

and a `contacts` table:

```
__________________________
|rel_id|user_id|friend_id|
--------------------------
```

The two tables are related on user_id.
How do I make a SQL query to retrieve all user's contacts?

Comment: You may want to consider reading a book on SQL or at least doing some minor research. This is a really trivial question.

Comment: more specifically read JOINS and you will find the answer !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding how JOIN works when 3 or more tables are involved. \[SQL\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql)

Comment: Did you do any research before you asked this question? Lets start with the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: I did consider using Join actually, but somewhy I had a doubht, so I asked here, sorry, I know it's a fundamental question. I haven't done programming for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query as follows:

```
SELECT 
 u1.firstname || ' ' || u1.lastname as User,
 u2.firstname || ' ' || u2.lastname as Contact
FROM
 users u1
INNER JOIN contacts c
ON u1.user_id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN users u2
ON c.friend_id = u2.user_id;
```

Basically, you use JOINS. You may want to read more about them.

**Reference**:

[A related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! The down-vote was probably a mistake, the new user still learning the ropes of SO.