# Is it possible to do a three-way join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm studying databases and SQL using Lynda.com and two textbooks. I'm enjoying it and making progress, but complex joins are confusing me. Single joins I can get my head around, but the example I give in this post just sends my head spinning.

The join I am trying to perform looks like this. I'm sorry if I describe it poorly, I'm not yet aware of how to properly describe these situations.

- `select lastvisit, lastpostid from user where id = 1;`
- `` select `post.threadid` where `post.postid` = `` the lastpostid from previous line
- `` select `thread.title` where `thread.threadid` = `` is the threadid from previous line

I want to be returned, in the end, `user.lastvisit` and `thread.title`, joining by the details I mentioned. If I were describing this join in pseudo-SQL I would say `select user.lastvisit where user.id = 1 and thread.title where thread.id = post.threadid from post where post.postid = user.lastpostid from user where id = 1`... it's a mouthful in English.

Is it possible to do this using pure SQL? I could do it using a script in a programming language, but I feel like there must be some way to do this using a complex join.

Comment: Actually,  in the end it boils down to just one-join. When you have : `A join  B join C` - it becomes `A_joined_with_B join C` - just trying to make the logic easier for you - think of it always as a binary function.

Comment: I like this question's help also _ [Understanding how JOIN works when 3 or more tables are involved. SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql)

Comment: Reinforcing Coffee's note above.   After you join A and B, think of that as one table (AB) that you are now joining C to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user.lastvisit, thread.title
FROM user
LEFT JOIN post ON post.postid = user.lastpostid
LEFT JOIN thread ON thread.threadid = post.threadid
WHERE user.id = 1
```

We're using left join in case the user has no posts

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is the perfect answer and really makes it seem less daunting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a 3-way join, retrieving the last visit information too:

```
SELECT t.title, u.lastvisit
  FROM thread AS t
  JOIN post   AS p ON t.threadid = p.threadid
  JOIN user   AS u ON p.postid   = u.lastpostid
 WHERE u.id = 1
```

You could almost do it directly following your outline query structure fairly closely, but this doesn't retrieve the last visit time, so it isn't quite what you're after.

```
SELECT thread.title
  FROM thread
 WHERE thread.threadid = 
       (SELECT post.threadid
          FROM post
         WHERE post.postid = (SELECT lastpostid FROM user WHERE id = 1)
       )
```