# How the Columns are rewritten when we INNER JOIN tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to understand how inner join works , And i was working on this example

In this example i have three tables

```
// people table
|people_id | people_name |
| 1        | Foo         |
| 2        | Bar         |
//orders table
| order_id | people_id | order_title   |
|   1      |   1       | First_title |
|   2      |   2       | second_title|
|   3      |   2       | Third_title |
//items table
| item_id |order_id | people_id | title  |
|   1     |   1     |   1       | Apple  |
|   2     |   1     |   1       | Pear   |
|   3     |   2     |   2       | Apple  |
|   4     |   3     |   2       | Orange |
|   5     |   3     |   2       | Coke   |
|   6     |   3     |   2       | Cake   |
```

I just INNER join these table using query

```
SELECT * FROM people INNER JOIN orders ON people.people_id = orders.people_id INNER JOIN items ON people.people_id = items.people_id;
```

And i got following result

[image]

i can't understand. How the third column(order_id) and sixth column(item_id) are written.

I mean `order_id`  and `item_id` may have many possiblities. for example they could be written like this

```
                          |order_id|                    |item_id|
                          |  1     |                    |  1    |
                          |  1     |                    |  2    |
                          |  2     |                    |  3    |
                          |  2     |                    |  4    |
                          |  2     |                    |  5    |
                          |  2     |                    |  6    |
                          |  3     |                    |  3    |
                          |  3     |                    |  4    |
                          |  3     |                    |  5    |
                          |  3     |                    |  6    |
```

So can someone plese Explain How these columns are exactly written ?

Comment: No answer, just down voting . Whats happening with SO

Comment: Are you asking this question: What controls the order of the rows in the result?

Comment: Do some research on how JOINS work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql

Comment: Indeed, what is happening to SO?

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  They have no inherent ordering.

The only exception is when you add an `ORDER BY` to the outer-most `SELECT`.

Your question seems to be about the ordering of the results.  Without an `ORDER BY`, the results can come back in any order -- and, in fact, different runs of the query can return results in different orders.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM people p INNER JOIN
     orders o
     USING (pe_id) INNER JOIN
     items i
     USING (order_id)
ORDER BY order_id, item_id;
```

Additional notes:

- This version uses table aliases.
- It is better to write out the columns you want rather than using `*`.
- The `USING` clause is convenient in this case.
- The presence of `pe_id` in `items` appears to be a poor database design.  You should get this value from `orders`.

Comment: My question is not about ordering the results ,My question is  their may be another possible results for order_id and item_id . why i get it in this way